# Mockito cannot create Spy of @Autowired Spring-Data Repository

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spy

I am trying to overlay my whole test environment with Mockito.spy functionality so whenever I want i can stub a method but all other calls go to default functionality.
This worked very well with the Service layer but I have problems with the Repository layer.

My setup is as follows:

Mockito - 2.15.0
Spring - 5.0.8
SpringBoot - 2.0.4

Repository:

```
public interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<ADBO, Long> {}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class AService {

    @Autowired
    ARepository aRepository;

    public ADBO getById(long id) {
        return aRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public Iterable<ADBO> getAll() {
        return aRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

The configuration for the spy:

```
@Profile("enableSpy")
@Configuration
public class SpyConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ARepository aRepository() {
        return Mockito.spy(ARepository.class);
    }
}
```

And my test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("enableSpy")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    AService aService;

    @Autowired
    ARepository aRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ADBO foo = new ADBO();
        foo.setTestValue("bar");
        aRepository.save(foo);

        doReturn(Optional.of(new ADBO())).when(aRepository).findById(1L);
        System.out.println("result (1):" + aService.getById(1));

        System.out.println("result all:" + aService.getAll());

    }
}
```

Now there are three possible outcomes to this test:

- aRepository is neither a mock nor a spy:
  `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
  Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
  Example of corr...`
- aRepository is a mock but not a spy (this is the result I get):
  `result (1):ADBO(id=null, testValue=null)
  result all:[]`
- aRepository is a spy (this is what I want):
  `result (1):ADBO(id=null, testValue=null)
  result all:[ADBO(id=1, testValue=bar)]`

I attribute this behavior to the fact that the spring instantiation of the repository is more complex in the background and the repository is not correctly instantiated when calling `Mockito.spy(ARepository.class)`.

I have also tried autowireing the proper instance into the Configuration and calling `Mockito.spy()` with the @Autowired object.

This results in:

```
Cannot mock/spy class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class
```

According to my research Mockito can mock and spy final classes since v2.0.0.

Calling `Mockito.mockingDetails(aRepository).isSpy()` returns `true` which leads me to think the object in the background was not correctly instantiated.

**Finally my question:**

How do I get a spy instance of a Spring-Data Repository in my UnitTest with @Autowired?

Comment: Why so complex? Annotate the field you want to spy upon with `@SpyBean` instead of trying to shoehorn a dedicated configuration class into place. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Comment: Using `@SpyBean` instead of `@Autowire` on aRepository results in the same behavior, it becomes mock but not a spy.

Comment: Why go to this effort and complexity to test around a repository when https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html spring boot can help you out?  Additionally this requires you to understand the underlying complexities of a repository and how it works.

Comment: There is an opened bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7033

Comment: did you try this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698827/spring-aop-aspectj-afterreturning-advice-wrongly-executed-while-mockingbefo/62809074#62809074

Answer (score 12):

You should use [`@SpyBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) from `spring-boot-test`.

This used to be broken (per Spring Boot issue [#7033](http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7033)) but it's now been fixed and supported since Spring Boot `2.5.3`.

If you still getting this error and can't update your Spring Boot version, you might want to try the work-around proposed by @Mateusz Zając in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68632497) to this question.

Comment: it doesn't work well for Feign client too. Is it a known issue?

Comment: As @Mateusz Zając indicated in a comment, the Github issue is now closed and this feature is supported since Spring Boot version 2.5.3

Answer (score 12):

**@SpyBean** now **works** with spring data repositories since spring boot version **2.5.3**

If you can't upgrade you can work around this by instantiating your spy as such in the test method body:

```
var yourSpy = Mockito.mock(FooRepository.class, AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo(real))
```